# Place a draggable image above marker in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to do this? I've got markers placed on the map, but above it, I want to add an image, that looks exactly like the marker, that I can drag. I want to achieve effect that I drag the image to the defined place simultaneously the marker will still stay there so I'm actually operating with copy of this marker.

Thanks.

Comment: What about just having two markers, one draggable one on top of one non-draggable one.

Comment: Yes, that's interesting thought, well in fact, that's really interesting thought :) Thanks! Let's call it the answer.

Comment: @duncan if you add it as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.